# Supend thread in lock() Without DEADLOCK

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

On the one hand I want to lock some critical section with 'Lock()', but on the other hand I want to let possibility of suspending a thread at some button's click (I know that the 'Suspend' function should not be used, but I really have no choice).

Possibly that other threads will want to enter to this critical section. 
How can I prevent the DEADLOCK?

If the 'Suspend' function was throwing exception (like the 'Abort()' function), there was no problem.
The monitor was released in the 'finally' statement...

For example:

```
static List<Thread> threadList = new List<Thread>();
public static List<Thread> ThreadList
{
    get { lock (_locker) { return SaveLists.threadList; } }
    set { lock (_locker) { SaveLists.threadList = value; } }
}
```

If I'll suspend the thread that locked the object, and after thate an another thread will want to set/get the list =>DEADLOCK.

Comment: Please include some code, it's not clear what exactly is your problem

Comment: SuspendThread causes deadlock.  Which is why you should **never** use it.

Comment: The supervisor of my project demanded me to use a button for suspending some thread by SuspendThread.

Comment: Can anyone give a solution to the problem?

Comment: There is no workable solution that includes calling `Thread.Suspend`. If you want to suspend a thread safely, the code in the thread has to cooperate by listening to some type of event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the solution is too simple!
I'm surprised at myself how I had not thought of before...

The thread that was responsible tosuspend the other thread should lock the critical section first, thus effectively ensure that the other thread will not be inside.

I know that I should not use the 'Suspend' function, but I was asked to use it, and I have no choice.

It's Too bad that instead of getting an appropriate response, my score has decreased, and the answers were along the lines of: "You must never use the function", even though I wrote that I had to use it, despite the dangers involved, and I know that in general its use is prohibited.

I'm very disappointed, and I think he does not fit the forum.

Comment: As you found out, you didn't actually have to use it.  :)